# $setUnion to merge array from multiple documents MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents in a collection as follows :

```
{ _id : 1 , data : [7,4,0] }
{ _id : 2 , data : [4,5,6] }
{ _id : 3 , data : [6,7,8] }
```

I want to union the `data` array from two or more documents.

The query I am using to find the union of `data` array of `id` 1 and 2 is:

```
db.coll.aggregate(
{
    $match : {
        _id: { $in: [1, 2] }
    }
},
{
    $group: { 
        _id: 0,
        s0: { $first: "$data"}, 
        s1: { $first: "$data"}
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        ans: { $setUnion: [ "$s0","$s1"]}
    }
}
).pretty()
```

But the query results in:

```
{7, 5, 0}
```

which seems to be the data of `id` 1 only.

> How to achieve the union between two or more documents on same array
>   field?

**PS: I'm using MongoDB 3.4**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For a more efficient query, use the **[`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#exp._S_reduce)** operator to flatten the arrays. This will allow you to concat any number of arrays, so instead of just doing a union of the two arrays from docs 1 and 2, this will also apply for other arrays as well.

Consider running the following aggregate operation:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": { "$in": [1, 2] } } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 0,
            "data": { "$push": "$data" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "data": {
                "$reduce": {
                    "input": "$data",
                    "initialValue": [],
                    "in": { "$setUnion": ["$$value", "$$this"] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "data" : [ 0, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
}
```

Comment: What  if I want to do intersection ,then initial value will be empty and result will be empty but input is nested array

Comment: You could use $addToSet instead of $push if you want unique values in the resulting array.

Answer (score 3):

just use `$last` instead of `$first` for `s1`

so the query becomes:

```
db.coll.aggregate(
{
    $match : {
        _id: { $in: [1, 2] }
    }
},
{
    $group: { 
        _id: 0,
        s0: { $first: "$data"}, 
        s1: { $last: "$data"}
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        ans: { $setUnion: [ "$s0","$s1"]}
    }
}
).pretty()
```

output:

```
{ "ans" : [ 0, 4, 5, 6, 7 ] }
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. What if I want to union on more than two documents ? What would be the group block if I want to union data of id 1,2 and 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$unwind` and `$group` with `$addToSet`,

- `$match` your conditions
- `$unwind` deconstruct `data` array
- `$group` by null and do `$addToSet` to get unique numbers form `data`

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: { $in: [1, 2] } } },
  { $unwind: "$data" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: { $addToSet: "$data" }
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6WedZ3LfiHw)